# Bash command to compare more than two files

Tags: bash

I have a load of txt files formatted as below. I would like to find out lines of text that are common in all the files. I know I can do this with two files in bash with comm but can I do it with more than two files (I have 204 of them)

File 1:

```
chrom         chrStart         chrEnd

chr1             1                         1001

chr1         11001                   12001

chr1          12001                   13001

File 2:

 chrom    chrStart          chrEnd   
    chr1.        1                 1001                      chr1.            9001                 10001
  chr1       12001               13001
```

The output should be:

```
File 1:

chrom     chrStart         chrEnd

chr1           1               1001

chr1        12001          13001
```

Comment: Your example isn't the correct use of `comm` from what I can tell. `comm` is used to compare two *sorted* files, but your examples aren't properly sorted (`chr1` comes before `chrom` in an ASCII sort). In your application, are the files sorted? And to be clear on your question, are you looking for a way to find all the lines that are identically common to ALL the files?

Comment: Yes I want to compare all the files to find out what is common. That is why I haven't sorted them as I don't think comm is appropriate

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Your problem statement says, *I can do this with two files in bash with `comm`*. Then the question becomes: is the order important? Is it possible one file might have lines `a` then `b`, but another have these two same lines but in a different order (`b` then `a`)?

Comment: Hi. No that is not possible. The files are in fact lexicographically sorted by the first column and then the second. The third column is always 9999 away from the first. B would therefore never come before a

Comment: I think you're going to end up with a script rather than a simple command line in this case. The "naive" but simple approach would be a script that (a) strips off and saves the heading, (b) runs `comm` pair-wise on two files, with the result of each pair being compared with the next file, (c) saved heading prepended to the final result of (b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this loop?:

```
sort < file1 > fileresult
for i in {2..204}; do
    comm -12 fileresult <(sort < file$i) > fileresult.tmp
    mv fileresult.tmp fileresult
done
```

Self explanatory, considering that you already know use of sort & comm.

awk example:

```
awk 'FNR==1{i++}
     {a[$0]++}
     END{
         for(x in a){
              if (a[x]==i){print x;}
          }
        }
     ' file{1..204}
```

Assumptions:

1. Same line is not repeated in single file.
2. The common lines in all the files are identical. No spacing/tabs difference.